# Why is manual Thread.Sleeping necessary before Process.Start here?

Tags: c#, android, stream

I have a scenario where I am reading a file on an android phone from a C# application by using adb.exe to get in to the phone's shell and reading the file by using a Process in the C# app. However, I need to use Thread.Sleep right before Process.Start here if I want it to actually work. Any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdInfo;

string resulterr = "";
string result = "";

cmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(" adb.exe ", "shell cat /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf");
cmdInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmdInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmdInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo = cmdInfo;

var output = new StringBuilder();
var error = new StringBuilder();

cmd.OutputDataReceived += (o, ef) => output.Append(ef.Data);
cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (o, ef) => error.Append(ef.Data);

//if I don`t have this Thread.Sleep, the error string is "device not found"!!
Thread.Sleep(5000);

cmd.Start();
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
cmd.WaitForExit();
cmd.Close();
resulterr = error.ToString();
result = output.ToString();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Any ideas why this works with the thread sleeping but doesn`t work without it?? I can run

```
shell cat /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf
```

from the command line ad naseaum with no delays and no issues -- why do I need them here??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my case the device was actually not ready to receive the commands. I waited for a good device status like this.

```
    ProcessStartInfo lcmdInfo1;

    lcmdInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo(" adb.exe ", "get-state");
    lcmdInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;
    lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardError = true;
    lcmdInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process cmd2 = new Process();
    cmd2.StartInfo = lcmdInfo1;

    var output = new StringBuilder();
    var error = new StringBuilder();

    cmd2.OutputDataReceived += (o, ef) => output.Append(ef.Data);
    cmd2.ErrorDataReceived += (o, ef) => error.Append(ef.Data);
    cmd2.Start();
    cmd2.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmd2.BeginErrorReadLine();
    cmd2.WaitForExit();
    cmd2.Close();
    lresulterr1 = error.ToString();
    lresult1 = output.ToString();
    cmd2.Dispose();

    //sometimes there is an issue with a previously issued command that causes the device status to be 'Unknown'. Wait until the device status is 'device'
    while (!lresult1.Contains("device"))
    { 
        lcmdInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo(" adb.exe ", "get-state");
        lcmdInfo1.CreateNoWindow = true;
        lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        lcmdInfo1.RedirectStandardError = true;
        lcmdInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd2 = new Process();
        cmd2.StartInfo = lcmdInfo1;

        output = new StringBuilder();
        error = new StringBuilder();

        cmd2.OutputDataReceived += (o, ef) => output.Append(ef.Data);
        cmd2.ErrorDataReceived += (o, ef) => error.Append(ef.Data);
        cmd2.Start();
        cmd2.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmd2.BeginErrorReadLine();
        cmd2.WaitForExit();
        cmd2.Close();
        lresulterr1 = error.ToString();
        lresult1 = output.ToString();
        cmd2.Dispose();
    }
 //now your device is ready. Go ahead and fire off the shell commands
```